# Hibernate wont write correctly floating point numbers to a MS SQL 2005 database

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Here is the case, I have a java double property mapped to a ms sql server decimal(18,3), it was float before I changed it to decimal but the outcome is the same. When I persist the java floating point number the floating point is lost. In other words ( java  -> db )2.0345678D -> 20345678.00 .  Does anyone have encountered anything like that. I cannot seem to find it as a known bug in hibernate. I did found that there is an issue with ms sql float and decimal points but not a real solution.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Hi peter, have you tryed to use BigDecimal isntead of decimal?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to [set precision and scale in Hibernate](http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/appfuse-user-hibernate-and-decimal-column-precision-td548279.html)

Note:

decimal 18,3 allows 3 digits after the decimal place. So `2.0345678D` would be `2.034` anyway,

Comment: I've set up the java property as   @Column(name="columnName", precision=3, scale=18, columnDefinition="decimal(18,3)")    but it still doesn't work.